# Coloring markers in a scatter plot according to RGB values with Plots.jl

Tags: plot, julia, visualization, scatter, plots.jl

I have been looking for a way to color markers in a scatter plot without creating an entire new series for every point. Is there a way to color them individually with different RGB values for each?

a single color gradient (the solution to the question asked in:
[How do you color (x,y) scatter plots according to values in z using Plots.jl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130093/how-do-you-color-x-y-scatter-plots-according-to-values-in-z-using-plots-jl))
is not what I´m looking for. Maybe if I could overlap 3 gradients, one for each RBG color, that could work. Thanks.

Comment: You can probably send a vector of colors as argument to the `markercolor` keyword, e.g.,
`colors = [RGB(r,g,b) for (r,g,b) in some_color_generation_strategy]
plot(x, y, markercolor = colors)`

Answer (score 4):

As Fredrik said, you can pass a vector... it's pretty flexible, and if your vector is too short it should cycle.

```
using Plots
scatter(sin, c=[:red, colorant"blue", RGB(0,1,0)])
```

[image]